# XPATH required for an input text field?

Tags: xpath

i have a text box in my web application,Where i need to give input. I am trying to find the xpath of the text box. the following error is thrown.

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"

HTML code:

```
<div class="input">
<input id="firstName" class="long" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" name="firstName
```

I want the `xpath` for `firstName` textbox.

Comment: why xpath and no jquery?

Answer (score 6):

```
//input[@type='text']
```

And this for generally targeting a text input (what I was after)

Comment: why `//id[text()[contains(.,'firstName')]]` not going to work?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
//input[@id='firstName']
```

Explanation:

- `//` search on all levels
- `input` for element nodes with the name of "input"
- `[@id='firstName']` having an attribute (`@`) with the name of "id" and a value of "firstName"

Comment: i have  tried all possible combinations,,but the same error is displayed

Comment: Element is not getting located                                                          div class="clearfix"> <div class="input"> <label class="mandatorylabel" for="firstName"> First Name <span class="mandatory"> </span> </label> <input id="firstName" class="long" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" name="firstName".

Answer (score 1):

at least 3 simple ways to get this:

```
1)Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='firstName']"));
2)Driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstName"));
3)Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#firstName"));
```

Comment: I have tried this xpath ("//*[@class='clearfix']//.[@class='input']//.[@class='long']") and got below cases.. how can i select the first one??????                        [input#firstName.long, input#lastName.long, input#middleName.long, select#salutation.long, input#emailAddress.long, input#emailAddressConfirm.long, input#phoneNumber.long, input#alternatePhoneNumber.long, select#locale.long]

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'firstName')]]
```

finding by text would always work.