# custom xpath for "id" "input box" doesn't return anything in firebug

Tags: html, xpath

This question might appear as duplicate of:
[XPATH required for an input text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593057/xpath-required-for-an-input-text-field)

but question is **why my custom xpath is not working**. Though it is working for buttons, plain text on page, links etc.
Here is the HTML of it:

```
<input id="uemail" class="input_text" type="email" value="" tabindex="1" size="30" name="user[email]" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"/>
```

For this HTML I tried to find it in `firebug`, I wrote:

1. `//*[text()[contains(.,'user_email')]]`
2. `//id[text()[contains(.,'user_email')]]`
3. `//*[id()[contains(.,'user_email')]]`
   but none of worked, what am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasons:

1. Because, You are looking for text using `text()` but there is no text(as per given HTML), like you might have in links, buttons, plain text on page etc,so remove it.

2. after `'contains'` you are looking for all elements just look for its type i.e. `id`

3. third you know that it's an input field so use `*` or `input`. 
`*` means any and `input` means that this is an input box.

So, finally it becomes:
`//input[contains(@id,'user_email')]`. 
Which I am sure will work.